# Github GraphQL Search with Filtering

Tags: search, github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

Based on my limited searching, it seems GraphQL can only support equal filtering. So,

Is it possible to do Github GraphQL searching with the filtering conditions of,

- stars > 10
- forks > 3
- total commit >= 5
- total issues >= 1
- open issues <= 60
- size > 2k
- score > 5
- last update is within a year

I.e., filtering will *all* above conditions. Is it possible?

Comment: This Q/A helped me find a [better Github search approach](https://medium.com/@suntong001/query-github-graphql-9a4547d33bad), FYI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When querying for repositories, you can apply a filter only for a certain number of the fields in your list:

- number of stars
- number of forks
- size
- last update

Although you cannot specify them in the query filter, you can include other fields in your query and verify the values in the client application:

- total number of issues
- number of open issues

While, in theory, you can also query for the number of commits, applying your specific parameter arguments, that query returns a server error, it most probably times out. For that reason, those lines are commented out.

Here's the GraphQL query:

```
query {
  search(
    type:REPOSITORY, 
    query: """
      stars:>10
      forks:>3
      size:>2000
      pushed:>=2018-08-08
    """,
    last: 100
  ) {
    repos: edges {
      repo: node {
        ... on Repository {
          url

          allIssues: issues {
            totalCount
          }
          openIssues: issues(states:OPEN) {
            totalCount
          }

          # commitsCount: object(expression: "master") {
          #   ... on Commit {
          #      history {
          #       totalCount
          #     }
          #   }
          # }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The specification for repository queries can be found here: https://help.github.com/en/articles/searching-for-repositories#search-by-repository-size

Comment: Terrific! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but an update of what I've collected so far.

- According to "[Select * for Github GraphQL Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348326/)", not all above criteria might be available in the Repository edge. Namely, the "total commit", "open issues" and "score" might not be available.
- The purpose of the question is obviously to find the valuable repositories and weed off the lower-quality ones. I've [**collected**](https://gist.github.com/suntong/30ca6ef2a7c32c966a045118fc57de6c) all the available fields that might be helpful for such assessment [here](https://gist.github.com/suntong/97a919c21e6adc53447f5059a34d334a).

A copy of it as of 2018-03-18:

```
query SearchMostTop10Star($queryString: String!, $number_of_repos:Int!) {
  search(query: $queryString, type: REPOSITORY, first: $number_of_repos) {
    repositoryCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          name
          url
          description
#         shortDescriptionHTML
          repositoryTopics(first: 12) {nodes {topic {name}}}
          primaryLanguage {name}
          languages(first: 3) { nodes {name} }
          releases {totalCount}
          forkCount
          pullRequests {totalCount}
          stargazers {totalCount}
          issues {totalCount}
          createdAt
          pushedAt
          updatedAt
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
variables {
  "queryString": "language:JavaScript stars:>10000", 
  "number_of_repos": 3 
}
```

Anyone can try it out [as per here](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/using-the-explorer/).

Comment: fwiw, there's a filter that you can apply to the issues field to fetch only open issues: `issues(states:[OPEN])`

Comment: thanks @DanielRearden, I've [updated my gist](https://gist.github.com/suntong/97a919c21e6adc53447f5059a34d334a/revisions#diff-58f7ec41ac0f54fc487fc086d0651ffe)