# Github GraphQL Repository Query, commits totalCount

Tags: search, github, repository, graphql, github-graphql

How to search for Github Repositories using GraphQL, and get its *total commits count* as well in return?

It looks strange to me that [all fields available describing Repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348326/) contains total count of commit *comments* but not total count of *commits*.

Comment: This Q/A helped me find a [better Github search approach](https://medium.com/@suntong001/query-github-graphql-9a4547d33bad), FYI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an example of how to get the total number of commits for the `master` branch in the [rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails) repository:

```
query {
  repository(owner:"rails", name:"rails") {
    object(expression:"master") {
      ... on Commit {
        history {
          totalCount
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: OMG bswinnerton, you are better than the Github insiders that support GraphQL -- they said that it is [impossible now and hard to do in future](https://platform.github.community/t/schema-request-repository-total-contributors-and-commits/5405). Amazing!

Comment: I may _be_ a GitHub insider 

Comment: @bswinnerton Please can tell me how I'll make request using C# to call API v4 query for getting commit count, folks count, watch count & Created Date for a repository?? I've list of some repository

Comment: what does ... on Commit mean?

Comment: @jjxtra It is an [inline fragment](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#inline-fragments)

Comment: This actually helped with GitLab's GraphQL API! Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

bswinnerton's answer works well, but not for repositories without a `master` branch.
In this case you can use `defaultBranchRef`

Here's an example of how to get the total number of commits for the **default** branch in the [rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails) repository

```
query {
  repository(owner:"rails", name:"rails") {
    defaultBranchRef {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          history {
            totalCount
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```