# Query with a lot of repo names

Tags: github-api

I have many (up to 2000) repository names. I need to know the number of stars in each of them. How to do this with the least amount of requests to the Github API? Not important version 3 or 4

Answer (score 0):

Each time you seek to minimize the number of API calls, you might want to consider the [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/), which is made to replace *multiple* REST requests with a *single* call to fetch the data you specify.

Example: [`hanksudo/githubstars`](https://github.com/hanksudo/githubstars), which list repository stars and info through Github v4 GraphQL API

In your case, you would need to modify the query to get any repository whose name matches one of your list. See if a [filter approach described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49353150/6309) here would apply.

[J. Gerbershagen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10478001/j-gerbershagen) recommends [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023883/query-with-a-lot-of-repo-names/57024570?noredirect=1#comment100671907_57024570) to enter as search term "`repo:xxx/yyy repo:fff/yyy`".

Comment: I can't figure out how to get multiple repositories in one request with their names like xxx/yyy

Comment: Can anyone show me query example for getting more than one repo by list of owner/repo names?

Comment: @J.Gerbershagen Your comment seems incomplete. Maybe you are still writing it?

Comment: just enter as search term repo:xxx/yyy repo:fff/yyy

Comment: @J.Gerbershagen OK. I have edited the answer to include your comment