# Cannot get OPEN projects using GitHub's GraphQL API with ProjectsV2

Tags: github, graphql

I'm currently working on a project that involves retrieving GitHub projects using GraphQL, and I've encountered an issue with querying projects by their open state. Here is the query I am working with formatted as a Python string *without* any attempt to get OPEN projects:

```py
query = f'''
query {{
    organization(login: {org}) {{
        projectsV2(first: {limit}, orderBy: {{ field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC }}) {{
            nodes {{
                id
                title
                repositories(first: 20) {{
                    nodes {{
                        name
                    }}
                }}
            }}
        }}
    }}
}}
'''
```

This query works, but returns all projects - open or closed.

Based on the ProjectsV2 documentation (see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#projectv2)), there is a boolean field `closed` that I should be able to use. There is also a ProjectsV2States enum (see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/enums#projectv2state)) that specifies two states: OPEN and CLOSED. Based on some examples I have seen when querying for issues within a repo, I see the `states` field used which I figured would transfer to projects.

Below are some attempts I have made to solve this issue:

#### `filterBy` Option

I tried using a `filterBy` option, but after a closer read of the schema, I don't believe this option is valid for ProjectsV2. Nevertheless I tried:

```
projectsV2(first: 100, filterBy: {state: OPEN}, orderBy: { field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC })
```

where I also tried:

- `filterBy: {states: OPEN}`
- `filterBy: {states: [OPEN]}`
- `filterBy: {closed: false}`

#### Specify Field Value

I also tried specifying fields directly:

```
projectsV2(first: 100, closed: false, orderBy: { field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC })
```

and these as well:

- `state: OPEN`
- `states: OPEN`
- `states: [OPEN]`

All of these queries returned a 200 response but with no data.

#### Possible Solution: `search`

It looks like some people have used `search` (see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344444/github-graphql-search-with-filtering) and [issue](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/40565)), but I am not familiar with this method. Might be the solution.

#### Less Elegant Solution: Filter after Query

I know I can do this and already have, but pagination is also giving me an issue so I can't query *all* projects (for some reason I am always missing 6 items regardless of the resource: projects, issues, repos, etc.). If the number of projects I have -- closed or open -- goes beyond the query limit of 100, then I won't be able to reliably get all open projects that I need. However, I know I will never have more than ~20 open projects at a time on GitHub so if I can filter the original query I don't have to worry about pagination or query limits.